# Vector of different types of template classes?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

The code relevant to the problem I'm having is below. I'm trying to write a neural net using Eigen. I want to use Eigen's tensors to implement layers for my neural net but I'm not sure how. Eigen's tensors require me to input two template arguments, a type and an int for the number of dimensions of the tensor. The only type I'm going to use is a double, but each Layer needs to take an input Tensor and return an output Tensor, possibly of different dimensions, so I need to have the Layer class have  a template for those two numbers. However, doing this prevents me from having a std::vector of Layers. Is there any way around this? Also, as you can probably tell, the Layer class is abstract because other classes are going to inherit from it (which is why I want to be able to put it in a std::vector). I've looked at Boost's variant class, but I'm not sure I can use it, because I don't think I can go and explicitly add every possible type of Layer I might use before running it, and I don't know if it's somehow possible to do that automatically using templates somehow.

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

template<int inputDims, int outputDims>
class Layer{
public:
    virtual ~Layer();
    virtual Eigen::Tensor<double,outputDims> fire(Eigen::Tensor<double,inputDims>) = 0;
    virtual Eigen::Tensor<double,outputDims> derivative(Eigen::Tensor<double,inputDims>) = 0;
};

std::vector<Layer> v; //Doesn't compile
```

Comment: `std::vector<Layer<10,20>> v;` for example, no good?

Comment: That compiles, but then I can't add Layer<3,4> if I want to.

Comment: A `Layer<10,20>` is not the same type as a `Layer<3.4>`.  This is no different than if you had a `Car` class and a `Chair` class, and wanted to put those in the same vector.  So the issue boils down to trying to come up with one container that can contain multiple types, and I'm sure there are duplicate questions and answers on SO.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, there are quite a few, and I looked at them, which is why I looked at boost::variant, but they only have a static number of templated classes, not some number that's determined at compile time and may change with other parts of the code. I might want to have a vector of `Layer<10,20>` and `Layer<3,4>`, or I might want to have a vector of `Layer<5,6>`,`Layer<4,2>`, and `Layer<6,4>` depending on whatever gets passed in.

Comment: @BadProgrammer99 -- So the purpose of storing these in a container is...?  Is it so that you can call `fire` or `derivative` on all the items at once?  If so, then the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can be used, but the container has to be of `BaseLayer*` (similar to the answer given).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's what I want to do, I'll take a look at the link you posted, thanks

Comment: @BadProgrammer99 -- ok, it's a little more involved when it comes to templates, but the visitor pattern is doable for this task.

Comment: You can try to look for `std::tuple<...>` may be this is that you want. You will be able to call `fire` and `derivative` with some template magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class BaseLayer 
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseLayer() {};
};

template<int inputDims, int outputDims>
class Layer : public BaseLayer
{
public:

    void fire() { std::cout << inputDims << ":" << outputDims << std::endl; }
    void derivative() { std::cout << inputDims << ":" << outputDims << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<BaseLayer *> v;
    BaseLayer *l1 = new Layer<10, 20>;
    v.push_back(l1);

    Layer<10, 20> *l11 = dynamic_cast<Layer<10, 20> *>(l1);
    if (l11)
        l11->fire();

    BaseLayer *l2 = new Layer<3,4>;
    v.push_back(l2);

    Layer<3,4> *l22 = dynamic_cast<Layer<3,4> *>(l2);
    if (l22)
        l22->derivative();

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
10:20
3:4
```

Comment: But then I can't call fire() or derivative() on the BaseLayer instances, right?

Comment: @BadProgrammer99 Yes, you can call them if you dynamic cast BaseLayer back into appropriate Layer. I have changed example a little because I don't know what `Eigen::Tensor` looks like and it won't compile without it. Used generic methods just to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: To further extend this you could pass the dimension information to the baseLayer class (via constructor), store it there and then use that information to do the right cast. That way you don't need to keep track of the Layers.

Comment: That should work really well. I didn't know dynamic_cast was a thing. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BadProgrammer99 Sorry forgot to mention, when you dynamic cast back, check that result is not `nullptr` (added check into example)